# cannot execute binary file: Exec format error while running java 11.0.7-open with sdkman

Tags: java

I installed `java 11.0.7-open` using `sdkman` and I get this error:

> `bash: /home/pi/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.7-open/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

when running `java --version` or `java -jar some_file.jar` (specifically 'SKlauncher 3-beta.15.jar').

Why do I get this error and how to make java work?

Comment: What is the output of  the command `file /home/pi/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.7-open/bin/java` ?

Comment: @Ephemeral if you mean the content inside the file, then it's encoded

Comment: No the result of the command `file /home/pi/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.7-open/bin/java`

Comment: `.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=092cfbfe7cf2936bdbc489b4ec39bebcff2b0b12, not stripped`

Comment: And what is your arch, 32 or 64-bit ?

Comment: @Ephemeral I think it's 64-bit. I use Raspberry Pi 4B, so it's probably 64-bit

Comment: What is the output of `uname -m` ?

Comment: @Ephemeral armv7l

Comment: I think it's a 32-bit version... try to install 32-bit executable file.

Comment: @Ephemeral Yes, it's 32-bit. Just checked on Internet

Comment: So... Can I install Java for 32-bit using sdkman?

Comment: Sorry I do not know.

Comment: Doesn't look that it's about 32 or 64 bit. That executable is for x86 (Intel) processors, not for ARM.

Comment: As Dirk points out the problem isn't just the bus width/address size (32 or 64 bits).  It's the [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture).  Pi's, like most smartphones, are ARM based.  But you indicate an `x86-64` binary; the 32-bit version of that is just plain `x86`, but it will still not work because it is an Intel/AMD ISA, like most laptops/desktops etc.  This is probably `sdkman`'s fault -- either it is misconfigured  or very poorly designed, I'm inclined toward the former.  There is no point in it if it cannot install the correct version for the platform.

Comment: @Dirk You should write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only 32-bit versus 64-bit is important, but also that the JDK is compiled for the ARM-processor. For that reason I prefer to use BellSoft LibericaJDK which has a Raspberry Pi-version and also includes JavaFX in case you want to run a JavaFX UI-application.

E.g. to use JDK 13 on Raspbian OS:

```
$ cd /home/pi
$ wget https://download.bell-sw.com/java/13/bellsoft-jdk13-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.deb
$ sudo apt-get install ./bellsoft-jdk13-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.deb
$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

When this is done, we can check the version again and it should look like this:

```
$ java --version
openjdk version "13-BellSoft" 2019-09-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13-BellSoft+33)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 13-BellSoft+33, mixed mode)
```

More info on https://webtechie.be/post/2020-04-08-installing-java-and-javafx-on-raspberry-pi/